# analyticity of f(x+iy)=x^3+ax^2y+bxy^2+cy^3

Tags: cauchy-riemann-equations

please have a look at the question,
[Necessary condition for analyticity of $f(x+iy)=x^3+ax^2y+bxy^2+cy^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178686/necessary-condition-for-analyticity-of-fxiy-x3ax2ybxy2cy3)
 to solve the question i started from
f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) since it is analytic it will hold the C-R equations.
$$
\begin{cases}
u_x = 3x^2+2axy+by^2\\
u_y = ax^2+2bxy+3cy^2
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
v_x(x,y) &= 0 \\
v_y(x,y) &= 0
\end{cases}
$$
so,
$$
\begin{cases}
3x^2+2axy+by^2&=0\\   
ax^2+2bxy+3cy^2&=0
\end{cases}
$$
ux,uy are partial derivative of u wrt x,y resp. Similarly applies for v.
After equating the equation 1 and 2, the answers comes out to be a=3,b=3,c=1
the answer seems to differ from the one that is in the given above link.

Is there some error in the answer?

Comment: You are assuming that $a,b,c$ are real numbers.  They are not given to be  and if they are real then the function is never analytic.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy well after equating the equations I am getting values of a,b,c in real numbers.

Comment: Your formulas for $u$ and $v$ are wrong. It is not true that $v=0$.

Comment: For $y=0$, this gives to you that $f(x)=x^3$ Hence your function is equal to the analytic  function $g(z)=z^3$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence if $f$ is analytic you have $f(z)=z^3=(x+iy)^3$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write down the real and imaginary parts of $a,b$ and $c$ and then the real and imaginary parts of $f$ to find out what $u$ and $v$ are.